# Error when clicking 'new project' in Intellij 12

Tags: intellij-idea

when clicking 'new project' it doesn't create it but instead spits out this error message on the console.....

```
[  10829]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Error during dispatching of java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(451,206),absolute(1321,483),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on frame1 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.intellij.openapi.module.UnknownModuleType cannot be cast to com.intellij.openapi.module.WebModuleType
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.WebModuleType.getInstance(WebModuleType.java:13)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.WebProjectTemplate.createModuleBuilder(WebProjectTemplate.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.modes.CreateFromTemplateMode.createSteps(CreateFromTemplateMode.java:119)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.modes.WizardMode.getSteps(WizardMode.java:51)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.AddModuleWizard.initModuleWizard(AddModuleWizard.java:136)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.AddModuleWizard.<init>(AddModuleWizard.java:78)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createNewProject(NewProjectUtil.java:73)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.NewProjectAction.actionPerformed(NewProjectAction.java:26)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:310)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:521)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:348)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
[  10831]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4  Build #IC-129.713 
[  10831]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - JDK: 1.7.0_21 
[  10831]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[  10831]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  10831]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - OS: Linux 
[  10832]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Last Action: WelcomeScreen.CreateNewProject
```

i searched around online and got the impression it was plugin specific but i removed the plugins folder and the problem still persisted....i also downloaded another Intellij Version 12 and ran that but i got the same error so im guessing it's environment related....

im running it on the latest version of Ubuntu

please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong place. Create an issue on http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Or just search... http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92381